# function javascript or jquery (if else)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following function in jquery

```
$("body").on("click", "a, button", function() {
     document.getElementById('carga').style.visibility='visible'; 
});
```

Basically it will look for all the type a links and add an onclick that will call an id element.

this works fine.

however, I need to create a condition for it to run if it is met.

the condition that I need for the above to be met is:

- if href exists (example: 123)
- href is NOT "#" (example: href is NOT "#")
- href is NOT "/" (example: href is NOT "/")
- href is NOT blank (example: href is NOT blank)

if this is true then execute the code given above

Could someone help me create that condition?

Comment: Why the php and python tags?

Comment: Buttons don't have an `href`, what is the condition for buttons?

Comment: In the case of the buttons I don't need any conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this).attr('href')` to get the href of the element. Then you can perform all the checks.

```js
$("body").on("click", "a, button", function() {
  if ($(this).is("a")) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (href && href != "#" && href != "/") {
      $("#carga").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
  } else {
    $("#carga").css("visibility", "visible");
  }
});
```

I added an extra `if/else` for `a` versus `button`, since buttons don't have `href`. You could also split them into separate handlers.

```js
$("body").on("click", "a", function() {
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  if (href && href != "#" && href != "/") {
    $("#carga").css("visibility", "visible");
  }
});

$("body").on("click", "button", function() {
  $("#carga").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

Comment: you are a genious! thank you very much this solved my problem!!! thanks!!

Comment: I just ran into another problem.

when the a contains the parameter target = "_ blank" the function remains active. (in other words it is loading).

is there a way to modify so that if it finds target = "_ blank" it won't load either?

Comment: Yes, just add another check for `$(this).attr("target") != "_blank"`. This is not complicated.

Comment: You can also put it in the selector: `a:not([target=_blank])`

Comment: solved everything I asked in just a few minutes.

this community is really great! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like.

```js
let href_str = '123'; // get href of anchor tag
if (!['/', '#', ''].includes(href_str)) {
  console.log('execute');
  // your code.
}
```

**EDIT:**

```js
function execute(href_str) {
  console.log('Href => ' + href_str);
  if (href_str && !['/', '#'].includes(href_str)) {
    console.log('execute');
    // your code.
  }
}
let arr = ['http://google.com', '', null, '/', '123', '#', '#456', 'google.com#something'];
arr.forEach(href => execute(href));
```

Comment: Umair Khan, all links are different. for example

link 1
link 2
link-askdjasldkjasldk
link-4304983049kelrtkjert

in that case how can I achieve something for the whole page without specifying the link.

Comment: You said not to execute on `/`, `#` or `blank`. It'll work for other `strings` / `links` / `href`.

Comment: if so it would work. only without the href link does it have /, # or blank

Answer (score 0):

Since your even handler binder is based on jQuery, I personally don't see why you are using an element selector based on JS, instead of sticking with jQuery. I recommend sticking to one standard, it will help you in the long run - either stick to pure JS or to jQuery.

This is how you can do this with jQuery:

```js
$("body").on("click", "a, button", function() {
var hrefAttr=$(this).attr('href');

// Check if href attribute is set
if(
    typeof hrefAttr !== typeof undefined && hrefAttr !== false
    &&
    // href is not blank, hashtag, or foreward slash
    hrefAttr !== '' && hrefAttr !== '#' && hrefAttr !== '/'
)
{
    $(this).show();
}
});
```

Be advised that your selector also includes buttons and href is an attribute used for `a` elements.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 method  (no jQuery)

```js
const el_carga = document.getElementById('carga')

document.body.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('a, button'))  return  // ignore others

  let href_str = e.target.getAttribute('href') || 'no href'

  if (!['/', '#', ''].includes(href_str))
    {
    el_carga.style.visibility='visible'
    }
  }
```